# what is the component typ or the domain of a button in abap

Tags: button, dictionary, structure, components, abap

i searched the web for some hours but could not found anything to the topic,
neither in english "abap component typ of button" nor in german "abap komponententyp Drucktaste".

I want to create a structure in the dictonary which should contain some buttons,
which i add into a Dynpro via the "Dict/Programmfelder-Fenster F6" in the Screen Painter and have access in a report via "TABLES: *structurename*" resp. class that handle the process after input (pai) for me.

The idea is to have full controll of all events and fields in a controller like in the Design Pattern Model View Controll (MVC).

```
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Module  STATUS_2000  OUTPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
MODULE status_2000 OUTPUT. " PBO
  SET PF-STATUS '2000'.
  SET TITLEBAR '2000'.

  caretaker->pbo( ).

ENDMODULE.                 " STATUS_2000  OUTPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Module  USER_COMMAND_2000  INPUT
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
MODULE user_command_2000 INPUT. " PAI

  caretaker->pai( EXPORTING
                iv_ok_code = ok_code ).
ENDMODULE.                 " USER_COMMAND_2000  INPUT
```

The handling for the default events like BACK, CANCEL and END which could be set in the PF-STATUS of the Dynpro and data components like e.g. UNAME (user name) and WERKS which can be easy added to a structure in the dictionary works fine that way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This does not make any sense. Why should a button be part of a data structure?

Comment: to get the control over the events triggert by the button in the pai() of the class

Comment: Please do take the basic screen (dynpro) programming courses. This is not how screen programming works. (You also might want to rethink the name "caretaker"...)

Comment: i allready had a basic screen programming course and now i'm experimenting with techniques i learned during my development time in java and the books i've read and courses i had in abap. the name _caretaker_ is like in my post before [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030923/abap-method-call-as-parameter-in-method-call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030923/abap-method-call-as-parameter-in-method-call) because it is the same class which should handle the table operation and the event handling

Comment: it looks like there is a way to create a buttun in a report [http://www.tricktresor.de/blog/drucktaste-neben-ausfuehren-button/](http://www.tricktresor.de/blog/drucktaste-neben-ausfuehren-button/) and there is a component type "DRUCKTASTE" but if you add a element with this type from a structure to a dynpro screen its a textlable and an input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here we go. I've got a solution.

I found the following help in german http://help.sap.com/saphelp_banking80/helpdata/de/d1/802352454211d189710000e8322d00/content.htm the same exist in english http://help.sap.com/saphelp_banking80/helpdata/en/d1/802352454211d189710000e8322d00/content.htm

If you add e.g. char1 or char7 into your dictionary structure and you add it in the screen painter to the dynpro you have the possibility to transform it into a button which have then the behaviour of a regular button.

- To transform the char-input-field after adding it to the screen you need to double click it. A Popup window will appear (Screen Painter: Attribute).
  At the bottom there is a section called Attribute with three tabs (Dict, Program, Display).
- In tab program deselect "Inputfield".
- In Screen Painter in menu bar: edit > convert > Pushbutton 
  (the field should now changed its look)
- In Popup window "Screen Painter: Attribute" in tab program deselect outputfield
- set the name/lable of the button above in the field text and the function code in the field FktCode

Now you have a button which is part of your structure and can be observed in your class.